# python code not being displayed on python 3.4.2 shell

Tags: python

```
print("hello")

def vendingMachine():

    count = 0
    totalCredit = 0
    coinNum = int(input("how many coins would you like to enter?:"))
    while count in range (coinNum):
         coin = float(input("enter coin: £"))
         totalCredit = totalCredit + coi
         count = count + 1
    print("you have £{0} in your bank.".format (round(totalCredit,2)))
    print("")
    print("choose your item:")
    print("")
    print("1.coca cola")
    print("2.lucozade")
    print("3.7up")
    print("4.fanta orange")
    print("5.pepsi")
    print("6.Diet pepsi")
    print("7.mountain dew")
    print("8.rubicon")
    print("9.Dr Pepper")
    print("10.sprite")
    print("")
    finalCredit = totalCredit
    round (finalCredit, 2)
    item = int(input("enter the number for your item:"))
    while item <1 or item >10:
        print("this item is not available.")
        item = int(input("enter the nuber for your item: "))
    if item == 1:
        finalCredit = totalCredit - 0.59
        print ("you now have a Coca cola can, costing £0.59.")
        print ("you have {0} remaining in your bank.".format (round(finalCredit,2)))
```

when i run it (f5) this comes up:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ===============================
>>> 
hello
>>>
```

how do i make it so the full code shows up not just 'hello'
im using python IDLE 3.4.2
i copied this from a youtube video
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not call your function. Please add these code at the end of your python file. And then run your program again.

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
   vendingMachine()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a line that calls the function right after the code where you define the function.

```
vendingMachine()
```

Run again and it will run other code.

You've *def*(ined) the function but never called it.